# Function overloads based on interface inheritance

Tags: vb.net, interface, overloading

Say I have a base interface, and another one inheriting from it :

```
Public Interface Parent
    {stuff}
End Interface
```

And

```
Public Interface Child
    Inherits Parent
    {other stuff}
End Interface
```

I also have a sub and its overload :

```
Public Sub doStuff(parameter As Parent)
     {do some stuff}
End Sub
```

And

```
Public Sub doStuff(parameter As Child)
     {do some other stuff}
End Sub
```

If I call the sub like this it calls the "child function" :

```
Dim myParam As Child = New SomeClassImplementingChild
doStuff(myParam)
```

However, is there any way to make it call the "child function" with something like this, assuming I don't know at compile time the type of the coolParameter :

```
Public Sub coolFunction(coolParameter As Parent)
    doStuff(coolParameter)
End Sub 

Dim myParam As Child = New SomeClassImplementingChild
coolFunction(myParam)
```

Comment: you could test the Type to see if it implements `IChild` and if so, cast it before calling the method.  The last part is sort of murky since `DoStuff` is already overloaded

Comment: The problem is that `coolFunction` does not know of IChild, so I can not test coolParameter to see if it implements it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround which is I guess the closest I'll ever get to a solution:

```
doStuff(Convert.ChangeType(coolParameter, coolParameter.GetType))
```

That will convert to the "real" type at Runtime, effectively calling the right function. However, the functions all have to be public to be called that way